# Python 3, post method misleading

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, python-requests, urllib

Here are two examples that demonstrate successful POST requests. But i cannot replicate this autonomously.

Example1

visually required: data={'SearchTxt':'bla'}

**actually required:** data={'page':'search', 'SearchTxt':'bla'}

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
a = session.head('https://www.axemusic.com')
session.cookies['Lm722stores'] = None
session.cookies.set('Lm722stores', '5h5i1rm6q3ur4mg67rs7kb77p4', domain='.axemusic.com', path='/')
response = session.post('https://www.axemusic.com/', data={'page':'search', 'SearchTxt':'bla'})
if response.text.find('Search results for bla') != -1: print('found')
else: print('not found')
```

Example2

visually required: https://stackoverflow.com data={'q':'bla'}

**actually required:** https://stackoverflow.com/search data={'q':'bla'}

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
a = session.head('https://stackoverflow.com')
session.cookies['prov'] = None
session.cookies.set('prov', '2922137c-e851-cd7e-8df4-9e5eb968ab33', domain='.stackoverflow.com', path='/')
response = session.post('https://stackoverflow.com/search', data={'q':'bla'})
if response.text.find('highlight">bla</span>') != -1: print('found')
else: print('not found')
```

Is there a way to make this process more autonomous. I'd rather not have to manually test every input in the browser and manually and examine the GET output before knowing what the `requests` actually requires to perform the POST.

Comment: What are you talking about? I am sorry I cannot understand. Could you make it clearer? What is "visually required"?

Comment: when you go to stackoverflow.com ... you have the option to search ... but this is not true with `requests` .... only `stackoverflow.com/search` allows you the option to search

Comment: It isn't related to `requests`. You just don't understand how site works. You have the option to search on `domain.com` doesn't mean all your requests are sent to this route. Obviously some or most of your requests are sent to other specifical routes.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd rather not have to manually test every input in the browser and manually and examine the GET output before knowing what the requests actually requires to perform the POST

Yes, by reading documentation for public APIs. E.g., https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

For non public APIs like axemusic you're on your own. It's like asking "how does the baker like his eggs cooked?" No idea